# Background task with result leads to compiler error FS0073

Tags: f#, background-task, f#-async

I am new to F# language but as far as I read `backgroundTask` [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/task-expressions#background-tasks) isn't limited to being only tasks with no result, however, when I change the following code I get compiler error `FS0073`

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   FS0073  internal error: Undefined or unsolved type variable: 'a

```ml
let sendSerializedPayload (writePayload, commandType: BaseCommand.Type) =
        Log.Logger.LogDebug("{0} Sending message of type {1}", prefix, commandType)
        backgroundTask { // <-- this used to be just task
            try
                do! connection.Output |> writePayload
                return true
            with ex ->
                Log.Logger.LogWarning(ex, "{0} Socket was disconnected exceptionally on writing {1}", prefix, commandType)
                post operationsMb ChannelInactive
                return false
        }
```

Is there something that I am doing wrong or not understanding or there is a compiler problem with backgroundTasks with results (I don't get such errors when switching from task to backgroundTask for task that does not have result?

Comment: What specific part of that code is the error on?

Comment: Background tasks with results are definitely allowed, so I suspect the compiler error is caused by something else. Can you provide a reproducible test case for what you're seeing?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/12978 reproducible example can be found here @BrianBerns

Comment: Well, that's certainly a shorter reproducible example than I expected! Definitely looks like a compiler bug to me.